# get sidekiq last job instance variable in retries_exhausted block

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

```
class EventMonitor
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options retry: 4
    sidekiq_retry_in { 10 }

    sidekiq_retries_exhausted do |msg|
      # do something with @response
    end

    def perform(country_code)
       @response = # call an API
    end
```

Hi, I have this worker. I want to call an API 5 times before giving up. but i want to log the last API call. I stored it in an instance variable and call it in the sidekiq_retries_exhausted block. it is of nil value. I also print the msg value but it only has jid, retry, args, exception, no instance variables AFAIK. what should I do? I want to log the last response if its the last retry. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `sidekiq_retries_exhausted` block is called with [2 arguments](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/cc611614338dedcb21252e66aac3514683124df1/lib/sidekiq/job_retry.rb#L222) - a message and an exception. So there is no way this callback can have an access to job internals.

Starting from Sidekiq 5.1 you can [add a *global* death handler](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#death-notification) via `config.death_handlers` that will have an access to the job instance, but I'd propose to look at the problem from a different angle:

- Why do focus on the last call only? There is no guarantee that the last failure is representative - for example, let's imagine that the first 4 attempts failed with 422 due to the wrong API call, but the last one failed just because of a trivial timeout (or other network error). In your logs you see something that can be ignored, but in fact, your worker seems to be broken.
- Why do you try to couple logging machinery to Sidekiq jobs implementation? Is it really different from other errors that might happen in other places within your app?

So, to summarize:

1. Logging should not be coupled to jobs implementation - it should be generic,
2. For maintenance reasons you might need to log *all* API calls regardless of their status, but at minimum you should log all failed ones, not just the last retry. This would *even simplify* your task to some extent - you could add logging machinery in just one place (HTTP client itself)...